# Assembly 8086 program

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am new to assembly language and this is some code that I didn't understand hoping that someone would help with it.

```
DATA SEGMENT
     VALUES DB 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
     ITEM DB 6
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
     ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
       MOV DX,AX
       LEA SI,VALUES
       MOV AL,ITEM
COMPARE: CMP AL,[SI]
         JZ Found
         INC SI
         LOOP COMPARE
         CLC
         JMP EXIT
Found: STC
EXIT: MOV AH,4CH
      INT 21H
      ENDS
CODE END
```

This program is supposed to look for number `(6)` among `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

I understand how it works in general but I have a few questions:

1. Why did we use `CLC` and `STC` ?? I know they put `CF` into zero and one but why do we use it??
2. Why did we use `MOV AH,4CH` in after the `EXIT` label??
3. After the start label why did we *say* the following:

   MOV AX,DATA
   MOV DX,AX

Why didn't we just *say*:
`MOV DX,DATA`

Lastly, Could someone suggest a good book to learn assembly??

Comment: oh boy! 3 editors at once! =P I kept the book recommendation bit.

Comment: search SO for book recommendations See: [SO Ninja Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=book+for+assembly+language&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1)

Comment: LOOP is 286+, you dont init cx anywhere anyways.

Comment: @bestsss: `loop` is definitely not 286+. All forms of `loop` are 8086 level instructions. The lack of initialisation of `cx` is true however.

Answer (score 2):

```
MOV AX,DATA

MOV DX,AX
```

This is wrong.

**Correct answer is:**

```
MOV AX,DATA   

MOV DS,AX
```

we cant send data from memory to segment registers(DS) directly . so we are sending through General purpose registers(AX).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm searches a number in a list of numbers.

If it is found, `CF` is set. If it is not found `CF` is cleared.

INT 21H is the MS-DOS service interupt. Function 4Ch ends the program with an error code in AL (which contains the number to be found).

```
DATA SEGMENT
     VALUES DB 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
     ITEM DB 6
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
     ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
       MOV DX,AX
       LEA SI,VALUES           ; DS:SI points to the VALUES structure
       MOV AL,ITEM
COMPARE: CMP AL,[SI]           ; Compare with number in list
         JZ Found              ; Jump to Found if equal
         INC SI                ; Try next
         LOOP COMPARE          ;
         CLC                   ; Clear CF (not found)
         JMP EXIT              ; Quit
Found: STC                     ; Set CF (found)
EXIT: MOV AH,4CH               ; End program with error code AL = 6.
      INT 21H
      ENDS
CODE END
```

Comment: I mentioned under the question but LOOP is 286, probably you want CMP SI, XXX (probably addr of ITEM) and jnz, instead of loop. Also SCASB is probably the best in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `LOOP` instruction is curious here. This instruction decrements `CX` and jumps only if `CX` is not zero. This means that the loop runs `CX` times, but `CX` is never set by the program.

`CX` is likely zero on entry, and the first decrement will make it 65535, so it will actually loop a maximum of 65536 times, searching past the end of the list if the element is not found.

To make it correct, add `MOV CX, ITEM - VALUES` before the loop start. Since `ITEM` comes right after `VALUES`, subtracting their addresses will give the number of bytes (elements) in the list.

Often a label is added to the end of a list to make such calculations more robust.

```
         VALUES     DB 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
         VALUES_END LABEL BYTE
         ; ...

         MOV CX, VALUES_END - VALUES
COMPARE: ; ...
         LOOP COMPARE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DX,AX
```

is wrong. It must be:

```
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
```

We write the address of the data segment to the `DS` register so that cpu knows which address to go look for our data. And we can't write `MOV DS,DATA` because of x86 instruction set limitations, i.e there is not such a function implemented in CPU. You have to use `AX` as a medium whenever writing segment addresses to segment registers.

Answer (score 0):

- The `CLC` instruction is used to "Clear Carry Flag" and the `STC` is used to "set the carry flag". These are process control instructions, used to control the processor action by setting/resetting the flag values.
- In ALP, we can only load a data into a segment register by, first loading it into a general purpose register and then we have to move it from this general register to the segment register, that is how the syntax is...
- `MOV AH,4CH` is used to terminate from the current process. By storing(moving=MOV) the hex value of `4CH` into `AH` register.

```
MOV AX,DATA 
MOV DS,AX
```

- `MOV AX,DATA` instruction is way of loading starting address of data segment in ax. then by using `MOV DS,AX` ,data segment gets initialized.

Comment: `mov DS, immediate` isn't encodeable as an x86 machine instruction, but it's not quite true that the source has to be a GP register.  It's also possible to `mov es, [bx]` from memory into a segment register (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), or even `pop ds` into it.  That isn't useful *here* for the `data` segment, but your statement didn't limit itself to that use-case.

Comment: Also, `mov ah, 4Ch` doesn't itself terminate the program.  The `int 21h` handler looks in AH for a call number; that's what it makes it relevant to set it to a DOS call number before running `int 21h`.